# Sharing security context across multiple glassfish servers

Tags: session, authentication, glassfish, single-sign-on, security-context

- My application is distributed in multiple components (Web Applications).
- The components are deployed on different glassfish servers.
- Each Glassfish server is running on a different host.

I'm using the provided Security Realm for authentication.

Is there a way, that a user that is already authenticated on server x, doesn't need to authenticate again on server y (single-sign-on)?

I was looking into session replication. But if I understand clustering correctly, this means I would have to deploy the applications to the whole cluster (each instance). What I need is a physically distributed solution.

My reason for this setup is not load balancing or high availibility. This is a customer demand.

Any ideas or workarounds? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an area where products like [Oracle Access Manager](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/identity-management/access-management/overview/index.html) come in for single-sign-on across multiple services. Oracle GlassFish Server (commercial product that includes [GlassFish Server Control features](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/application-server/glassfish-server-control-ds-072078.pdf)) has a JSR 196 JAAS Provider for Oracle Access Manager. Check out the [How-To](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/glassfish/documentation/howto-170276.html) document on setting it up.

Hope this helps.